# My HTML template website is not showing certain images and text on my mobile

Tags: html, image, templates, mobile

I have edited an HTML website and certain images are not showing on my mobile however they show perfectly on my PC!
Can anyone advise please on what i need to do? Maybe change some code.
I have added the relevant code (I think) below!
I am a neewbie so please handle with care!
Thank you so much
I have attached the 2 versions (PC and Mobile, which shows the Beauty and Elgegance wording as well as the Read more And See Our Work options)

Regards
Jules

```
<!-- Slider -->
<div id="main-slider">
    <div class="ms-layers-template">
        <div class="master-slider ms-skin-black-2 round-skin" id="mainSlider">
            <div class="ms-slide slide-2" data-delay="4" style="z-index: 11">
                <img src="css/ms-style/blank.gif" data-src="images/main-slider/bg1.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum dolor sit"/>

                <h3 class="ms-layer bold-title"  style="right:0; left:0; text-align:center; top:205px; color:#000"
                    data-effect="bottom(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="400"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                ></h3>
                
                  <h1 class="ms-layer bold-title"  style="right:0; left:0; text-align:center; top:243px"
                    data-effect="bottom(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="700"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                >Creating Art </h1> 
                                  
                <a href="#" class="ms-layer btn btn-default btn-try-class btn-yellow border-transparent" style="left:440px; top:340px"
                            data-effect="bottom(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="900"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                >Read More </a>
                
                <a href="#" class="ms-layer btn btn-default btn-try-class border-transparent" style="left:600px; top:340px"
                            data-effect="bottom(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="950"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                >See Our Work </a>
               
                 
            </div>
            <div class="ms-slide slide-1" data-delay="4" style="z-index: 10">
                <img src="css/ms-style/blank.gif" data-src="images/main-slider/bg.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum dolor sit"/>
               
               <h1 class="ms-layer bold-title"  style="left:0px; top:210px; color:#ffffff"
                            data-effect= "right(90)"
                            data-duration="600"
                            data-delay="300" 
                            data-ease= "easeOutQuart">
                              Beauty & Elegance
              </h1>
                
               <h3 class="ms-layer title-2"  style="left:0px; top:265px; color:#ffffff"
                            data-effect= "right(90)"
                            data-duration="600"
                            data-delay="600" 
                            data-ease= "easeOutQuart"></h3>
                    
           <a href="#" class="ms-layer btn btn-default btn-try-class btn-yellow text-uppercase border-transparent" style="left:10px; top:330px"
                            data-effect="bottom(20)"
                            data-duration="600"
                            data-delay="700"
                            data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                >Read More </a>
                
                <a href="#" class="ms-layer btn btn-default btn-try-class text-uppercase border-transparent" style="left:180px; top:330px"
                            data-effect="bottom(20)"
                            data-duration="600"
                            data-delay="800"
                            data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                >See Our Work </a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="ms-slide slide-3" data-delay="4" style="z-index: 12">
               <img src="css/ms-style/blank.gif" data-src="images/main-slider/bg4.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum dolor sit"/>     
                 
              <h3 class="ms-layer three-slide"  style="right:195px; top:220px;"
                    data-effect="top(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="200"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo"
               ></h1>
                
               <h1 class="ms-layer bold-title slide-three"  style="right:0px; top:252px;"
                    data-effect="top(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="400"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo">Modern & Contemporary</h1>
                    
           <a href="#" class="ms-layer btn btn-default btn-try-class btn-yellow border-transparent" style="right:520px; top:330px"
                            data-effect="bottom(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="600"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                >Read More </a>
                
                <a href="#" class="ms-layer btn btn-default btn-try-class border-transparent" style="right:340px; top:330px"
                            data-effect="bottom(20)"
                  data-duration="600"
                  data-delay="700"
                  data-ease="easeOutExpo"
                >See Our Work </a>
```

I have tried uploading the images again and this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't attached the css so I can't replicate your code exactly, but you might need to adjust the sizes and positions of the images based on different screen sizes. This is done using media queries.

Edit: I don't have your exact images so I used random ones from the internet, and they seem to be working fine even in mobile view. Try using inspect element (Ctrl + shift + I) and in the elements tab, click your image tag and it'll show you where it's located on your screen. You can adjust the width of the screen and see at which point it "dissappears", then use media queries to make them visible on the screen at that screen size. I'm assuming you know what those are since you've worked with CSS?
[image]

Comment: Thanks guys!! I've attached the CSS code now

Comment: Also, in the original question you said you "attached 2 versions, PC and Mobile". You don't need two seperate versions of HTML, CSS media queries can handle the styles for you for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the css code of the HTML. I suggest you check the positions of the div. Also, use media queries.